# Update column with generated UUID

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to update column value with a generated UUID with different value on each rows?

```
UPDATE TABLE 
    SET id = replace(cast(uuid_in(md5(now()::text)::cstring) as varchar), '-', '');
```

I've used that code but resulted in every row on `id` column has the same value. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
replace(cast(uuid_in(md5(now()::text)::cstring) as varchar), '-', '')
```

This line is returning something like : 414079b5c096f2defa6a4ce8f1880e2c

Supposed I have this table :

```
ID ColumnA
1  testA
2  testB
3  testC
```

I would like to update every value on ID column become like :

```
ID                                ColumnA
414079b5c096f2defa6a4ce8f1880e2c  testA
414079b5c096f2defa6a4ce8f1881f3d  testB
414079b5c096f2defa6a4ce8f1882g4e  testC
```

But what I get from that query is, every value on ID column has the same value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`now()` returns the time at the start of the **transaction**.

You want to use `clock_timestamp()`

Quote from the manual:

> `clock_timestamp()` returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command

More details in the manual:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT

---

Btw: Postgres already has a built-in UUID generation function. You might want to have a look at that as well: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to insert the UUID value generated from the query, not the timestamp..

Comment: So what does your function `uuid_in` do? How does it generate the UUID? I assumed it does that based on the passed value of `now()` which will not change during the runtime of the statement thus passing the same value to your function - which I assumed would then generate the same UUID. If that is not the case you need to supply more details about what this function is doing

Comment: Ahhhh, Ic now. You're right. Thanks, I've changed `now` into `clock_timestamp()` and it's worked! :)